Where are RST drivers for 7th gen cpus for windows 8.1?
I am planning to build a gaming pc that can run windows 8.1. However, I need rst drivers for a 7th gen cpu that I want to use with windows 8.1 which I cannot find. I would appreciate help to find the correct drivers for my system.
Specs:

CPU: intel i7-7800X

Motherboard: ASUS PRIME Z270-A LGA1151 DDR4 DP HDMI DVI M.2 USB 3.1 Z270 ATX Motherboard

Storage: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB M.2 SATA Internal SSD (MZ-N6E1T0BW)



If you don't intend using RAID then you don't need it.

It is entirely possible that there are no Windows 8 drivers. That board was released 2 years after Windows 10 was. You might have some luck with the Windows 7 or 10 drivers at https://www.asus.com/us/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-x299-a/helpdesk_download?model2Name=PRIME-X299-A

You only have one SSD. Why do you need RST drivers?

@Ramhound Because on my other pc, I required them even though I only had 1 ssd with no RAID. The install didn’t work until I got the drivers and plugged them in.

The drivers would have only been required if you enable Intel RST within the firmware then tried to install Windows to the RAID.  I can promise you, as an owner of multiple Intel motherboards that support IRST, IRST drivers are NOT required unless you enable it and install Windows to the RAID.  Since you only have one SSD, not only would you gain nothing from a IRST setup, it does not appear Intel has released compatible Windows 8.1 drivers for your hardware.

Intel RST 14.8.16.1063 was the last version to support Windows 8.1, and is no longer supported, Intel recommends updating to a supported version. Intel removed IRST 14.x back in 2021 from it's website. I also don't believe your motherboard even supports IRST, I am almost certain, it was a feature for 8th Generation and newer.


However, I need rst drivers for a 7th gen cpu that I want to use with windows 8.1 which I cannot find.

Intel RST is only supported by 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, and 12th and 13th Generation Intel processors and their respective motherboards. So based on that fact the hardware you describe does not actually support Intel Rapid Storage Technology.
Source: What Intel® Rapid Storage Technology Driver Is Supported on My Platform?
Intel also remove the Intel RST 14.x drivers which were the last version to support Windows 8.1 back in 2021.

Intel® RST 14.X is End of Life now and no support for any further bug fixes and security fixes on this baseline will be provided starting June 2021. Intel will be removing the 14.X drivers from its website.

Source: End-of-Life (EOL) Announcement for Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) 14.X Release

I would appreciate help to find the correct drivers for my system.

The drivers you seek do not actually exist.  Your hardware does not actually support Intel RST, even if you did have supported, the only drivers being distributed by Intel does not support Windows 8.1
